# Vertx and port based routing

Tags: load-balancing, vert.x, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

I want to use my Vertx web app with a Network Load Balancer. However, NLB does not work with path-based routing. I was not able to find solutions online.

Is it possible to get the entire query in Vertx as a string and then call the appropriate handler for NLB?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in GCP called [URL maps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map) that is similar to Path-Based Routing in Amazon. If you want to move specific traffic to a specific server, using url-map you can select what backed service you want to reach for a specific traffic.